# Problem with WCF Web Service in SP2010

Tags: 2010, deployment, web-services, wcf

I've followed [this tutorial](http://mstecharchitect.blogspot.com/2010/03/hosting-wcf-service-inside-sharepoint.html) and also [this one](http://answers.oreilly.com/topic/1404-how-to-customize-wcf-services-in-sharepoint-2010/) (tried every possible combination of those) to deploy a custom WCF service in Sharepoint 2010.

But I'm not having any luck. Once the service is deployed, I tried to access it and get the annoying and undescriptive error:

```
XML Parsing Error: no element found
Location: http://mysharepointsite/_vti_bin/folder/service.svc
Line Number 1, Column 1:
```

I can't find any description of it. There's nothing in the event log.

Any ideas?

Thank you

**UPDATE**

The .svc file contains the following:

```
<%@ServiceHost Language="C#" Debug="true"
    Service="MyNamespace.MyServiceClass, $SharePoint.Project.AssemblyFullName$"
    Factory="Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Services.MultipleBaseAddressBasicHttpBindingServiceHostFactory, Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ServerRuntime, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>
```

I've added the .svc extension to the replaceToken section in the .csproj to get the `$SharePoint.Project.AssemblyFullName$` replaced by the actual assembly full name.

Comment: What's in your svc file?

Comment: Ensure that the WCF service you deploy in SharePoint is on .NET 3.5. SharePoint 2010 does not support .NET 4 currently.

Comment: @JamesLove I've updated the answer including the content of the .svc file.

Comment: @AmitKumawat Yes, the project is in .NET 3.5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been able to fix this starting from zero following [this](http://ranaictiu-technicalblog.blogspot.com.ar/2011/03/sharepoint-2010-create-custom-wcf.html?showComment=1332967074505#c4428695944752976579) guide

Answer (score 2):

Follow this steps from this article : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff521581.aspx

By the way, You can choose to have the WCF without the factory. Just supply the configuration in a separate web.config and place it along with your SVC file.